# Django ManyToMany Field add() not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have a field in my Django model defined as:

```
def get_field(**kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('related_name', '+')
    return models.ManyToManyField('app.MyOtherModel', **kwargs)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    MY_FIELD = 'A label for my field'
    my_field = get_field() # wrote function to DRY creation of fields
```

But whenever I try to add something to the field, it doesn't work:

```
foo = MyOtherModel.objects.create(...)
m = MyModel.objects.get(...)
m.my_field.add(foo)
m.my_field.all() # returns []
```

Doing some digging into Django source code, the `ManyRelatedManager.add()` function (in `django/db/models/fields/related.py`) works correctly, with `self.through.objects.all()` returning the right object at the end of the function, but `self.all()` doesn't, leading me to think the problem is in `get_queryset()`:

```
# printing self.through.objects.all() @ related.py:978
[<MyModel_myothermodel: MyModel_myothermodel object>]

# printing self.all() @ related.py:978
[]
```

Is the problem in the fact that I have both `MY_FIELD` and `my_field` defined in `MyModel`? Or maybe in how I generate the `ManyToManyField`? Or is there some other issue?

**UPDATE**: The issue is in `related.py` in the `get_queryset` function. `self.core_filters` is set to `{'+__year': 2015}`, however, when I query `qs.values('+__year')`, I get `{'+__year': None}`. (`year` is another field in the model)

Comment: You shouldn't generally mess about with the way fields are defined. There's a whole lot of metaclass stuff that makes the declarative syntax work, and I doubt that it would work with your separate function.

Comment: Why do you have the weird setup for your `my_field`? Wouldn't a normal m2m field does your work?

Comment: Roseman- the migration file worked, though. You still think it's not the best? Would it work better if I maybe did `MY_FIELD_LABEL` instead? // Wang- the weird setup is because I have around 50 ManyToMany fields, and I'd like to be able to access the names of the fields from the class level.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever been so curious about exactly what someone's doing and why as this question... You may not want to reveal more about it, but I'm definitely curious if you don't mind divulging more..? Maybe there's a better way entirely..?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my answer in old Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name

I need to specify unique `related_name` values, even if I use `+`. So I need to do `related_name='foo+'` and `related_name='bar+'`